# How to resolve Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 in my first flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

I recently come from java and try to make my first app in flutter in android studio in windows 10.
I tried first sample code in my real android device and got this error.
I cant find proper after struggling 5 hours

In console get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
> NDK at C:\Users\10\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: add JDK and JRE in you path variable as environment variable

Comment: still problem not solved

Comment: `Tools->Flutter->Open For Editing in Android Studio` try to build your project with this build. If still facing the issue after that, In android studio, Open SDK Manager  and download NDK. It is available under SDK tool option.

Comment: append them in path

Comment: ndk downloading start , it may be 1gb, i will comment after it complete

Comment: problem solved by installing ndk

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing NDK installation. Please confirm if highlighted item is installed
[image]

Comment: how to change it, by downloading exe file or by code ?

Comment: I found jdk-11.0.11_windows-x64_bin.exe,  is it right ?

Comment: it is downloaded , now i trying to install it

Comment: after restarting android studio,
problem not solved

Comment: C:\Users\10>java -version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS

Comment: lets clear these comments so the future reader can get the better help.